# Laravel Valet 404 Error When Trying to View Site

Tags: laravel, laravel-valet

I just cloned a repo from GitHub for a Laravel site and running it locally on valet.

I'm getting a 404 - Not Found error when I try to visit tmye local dev site, however I have the root folder in one of my valet paths directories, and have also tried running valet link in the root directory.

My other sites running in the same directory are loading just fine.

I've also tried uninstalling and reinstalling valet.

Any other ideas? I've tried everything I could find when searching the error.

Comment: What repo did you clone?

Comment: Its not a public one, but its the same as others I have working

Comment: Valet only knows how to serve certain types of projects out of the box. Otherwise, it will fall back to its default driver. If this has a custom directory structure - namely one that has its own webroot directory - you have to tell Valet how to serve it. Look into [Custom Valet Drivers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/valet#custom-valet-drivers) to achieve this. If it's a one-off project, consider using a [Local Driver](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/valet#local-drivers) in the application root.

Comment: Its a pretty standard Laravel project, so I don't think it would need a custom driver since the others run on it just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution:

Laravel likes a "public_html" directory while valet likes "public", so I created a symbolic link folder named public and all is fine and dandy.

EDIT

This no longer seems to be an issue with valet, it recognizes both `public` and `public_html` directories